# Should I always equip 3 weapons?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

I know there is a gauge that fills up to 100% over time, but because of lack of resources, I've only been making 1 really powerful upgraded weapon at a time, so my other 2 weapons are significantly weaker.

I know the game tells you to switch weapons mid-combat, but they deal way less damage. My allies are constantly switching to less powerful weapons, so can I just unequip those?

What are the benefits / drawbacks to having 3 weapons equipped VS equipping just one powerful one?

Comment: The only benefit I have seen is that is supposedly modifies your special moves if you are at 100% with the selected weapon (which then resets it). I personally only equip 2 weapons each, but I am really not sure that is even required. Though I would say there is little point upgrading weapons, you are likely to find a much better weapons quickly, and the game really isn't difficult if you just keep equipping the best weapons as you find them.

Comment: @musefan Yeah that's what I've been finding too. Not sure if there were some tactics that are revealed later that kind of force you into equipping 3. It seems like a good idea when you look at it, but it doesn't play very well and I just use the best weapon available.